# How unique is the HttpSession ID?

Tags: java, session, servlets, session-cookies

I am going to uniquely identify a user by storing a unique ID in his/her cookie. HttpSession ID is a good choice from my google search. Just wanted to know how unique it is ? Is it unique to the webcontainer or once it expires , will it get regenerated ? If it repeats, all my user login can go for a toss.Need some expert opinion on using sessonID as a unique identifier for my users.

Comment: Seems safe to say this will vary based on which servlet container you use; which I think bolsters the idea that you could also just easily use a "unique id generator" of your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A session ID must uniquely identify a session on a server, or on a cluster of servers. You don't have any guarantee of uniqueness across restarts. Why don't you simply use a database sequence, or a [UUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html)?

Answer (score 8):

Session IDs are unique and meaningful only for the lifetime of a session. A session ID identifies a session: nothing more, nothing less. It does not identify a user.

You cannot and should not rely on session IDs ever being reused, let alone for the same user.